# How to restore backup file in navicat?

Tags: postgresql, navicat

I am a Navicat user and I recently need to clear my database as I backup my file and clear all the database but while restoring it return message success but there is no table and views. Following Image shows my explanation:
[image: Image shows successful message]

[image: But there is no table and views from restore]

[image: And Also the checkbox is disabled]

first image: Image shows successful message,
second Image: But there is no table and views from restore,
third Image: And Also the checkbox is disabled.
I appreciate your help thank you

Comment: Could you open this backup file without using Navicat, and check the content? It looks like this backup only contains the sequences and nothing else.

Comment: thank you for your comment but the extension is .nb3 so, I have not look that one.
I backup this file and select everything while backup. and Yeah, I only got sequences. Do you know how do I turn that into tables? thanks

Comment: A sequence cannot turn into a table, impossible. You could ask the Navicat Customer Center to help you out. I never made any backup using this tool, only pg_dump because that's the default and reliable way to make a backup. That's also how other tools do it, they use pg_dump

Comment: Sure thank you @FrankHeikens for your help. I will never do this kind of mistake anymore.